# Subnautica: 2nd fragment of seaglide not there

Tags: subnautica

My friend wants the seaglide, so we were searching around the internet where to find them and with a result: I found them.

Next my friend wants the fragments so I showed him where they are and he finds only one fragment. The 2nd fragment is just not there. Please can you help me so I can help my friend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fragments do not always spawn in the same location. There are *some* locations where *certain* fragments are guaranteed, but most locations are randomly generated.

For example, the PRAWN and Seamoth fragments inside the Aurora are guaranteed spawns.

The Seaglide fragments can be found all over the Safe Shallows and Kelp Forests, especially near the wrecks or damaged life pods.